# First call to function to change state doesn't update any field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, jsx

So basically I am integrating GraphQL with a React web application to do some testing and to learn a bit more about the stack (forgive me if I am a newbie).

Just to resume it I basically have a book library app, where we have a list of books and a list of authors, and an author can write many books and a book is associated to an author.

I have 1 base class component where lives my logic (at the moment is the root file app.js), you can see below the code:

APP.JS

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";

import BooksList from "./components/Books/Books";
import AddBook from "./components/AddBook/AddBook";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql"
});

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    genre: "",
    authorId: ""
  };

  addAuthorHandler = (e, name) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      [name]: e.target.value
    });

    console.log(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <div className="bookList">
          <BooksList />
        </div>
        <AddBook addAuthor={this.addAuthorHandler.bind(this)} />
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

the issue is related to the addAuthorHandler function, the first time it gets called it receives the values but the state isn't updated properly.

As the booklist component is not important for this case (since it only displays books nothing more), the AddBook component is referencing the function addAuthorHandler in the prop, code below:

```
import React from "react";
import { Query } from "react-apollo";
import { getAuthorsQuery } from "../../graphql/queries/queries";
import Classes from "./AddBook.module.css";

const getAuthors = ({ data: { authors }, loading }) => {
  let render = <option disabled>Loading authors...</option>;

  if (!loading) {
    render = authors.map(author => {
      return (
        <option value={author.id} key={author.id}>
          {author.name}
        </option>
      );
    });
  }

  return render;
};

const addBook = props => {
  return (
    <div className={Classes.addBook}>
      <form className={Classes.form}>
        <div className={Classes.formBlock}>
          <span>Book Name</span>
          <div>
            <input
              className={Classes.input}
              type="text"
              onChange={e => props.addAuthor(e, "name")}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className={Classes.formBlock}>
          <span>Genre</span>
          <div>
            <input
              onChange={e => props.addAuthor(e, "genre")}
              className={Classes.input}
              type="text"
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className={Classes.formBlock}>
          <span>Author</span>
          <select
            className={Classes.select}
            onChange={e => props.addAuthor(e, "authorId")}>
            <Query query={getAuthorsQuery}>
              {data => {
                return getAuthors(data);
              }}
            </Query>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default addBook;
```

Above I have an onChange method that references the addAuthor prop and pass the event and the name of the property to be updated inside the state.

The first change never happens.

At the moment when I load the app for each input when I write 'a', the state is empty for that property even the value is being passed to the function handler if I write on more key like 'ab' the state updates with 'a'.

The expected result is to make the first change work like it is currently for the other changes.

Any help with this guys, and a possible explanation for the issue?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello! Need example - show lite example. Throw away css and other what not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` works in an asynchronous way. This means calling `this.setState` will not immediately change this.state variable. You need to implement a callback for that. something like-

```
addAuthorHandler = (e, name) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      [name]: e.target.value
    }, function () {
      console.log(this.state)
    });    
  };
```

Comment: hmmm thanks for the answer, I didn't saw setState being handled as a promise till now. is it a good approach to await the change of the state?

Comment: Great Thank you :)